# Реализация самостоятельно движущегося объекта на Java AWT

Tags: java, awt

Я уже реализовал движение объекта по нажатию клавиш, но пока не знаю, как сделать так, чтобы он двигался самостоятельно. Первое, что приходит на ум, - это использование таймеров. Я прав? Если нет, то не могли бы вы мне дать совет?

Comment: перерисовка по таймеру, и в каждом кадре скорость*дельта времени

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете реализовать самостоятельно движение, используя таймер. В каждый момент срабатывания таймера необходимо вызывать функцию перемещения, которые вы используете сейчас для ручного перемещения по нажатию клавиш